# ASP.NET MVC Updating Master-Detail Records in Single HTTP Post Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm teaching myself C# and MVC but have a background in SQL. When updating an existing master-detail set of records in a single action (let's say for instance a customer order and order details), updating the master record is no problem. Regarding the detail records, I'm seeing examples that simply delete all existing details and then add them back in rather than add, delete or update only what's changed. That seems easy and effective but involves unnecessary changes to database records and might be an issue in complex relationships.

I've tried writing code that checks the existing values against posted values to determine the right EntityState (Added, Deleted, Modified, Unchanged) for each detail. Accomplishing this using LINQ Except and Intersect works but seems to cause an unexpected performance hit.

(Instead, I could load the original values in an "oldValue" hidden field in the original GET request to compare to the POST values except that would be unreliable in a multi-user environment and seems like a bad idea.)

I'll be happy to provide code examples, but my question is more about best practices. Is there a preferred method for updating existing master-detail sets of records?

EDIT: I've added the code below in response to questions. In this example, our application allows additional attributes to be attached to a product, kept in a separate table ProductAttributes. The view allows the user to edit both the product and the attributes on the same webpage and save at the same time. The code works fine but seems slow and lags at SaveChanges.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Product product) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        // Establish entity states for product attributes.

        List<ProductAttribute> existingAttributes = new List<ProductAttribute>();
        existingAttributes = db.ProductAttributes.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Sku == product.Sku).ToList();

        // Review each attribute that DID NOT previously exist.
        foreach (ProductAttribute pa in product.ProductAttributes
            .Except(existingAttributes, new ProductAttributeComparer()))
        {
            if (pa.Value is null)
            {
                // Value didn't exist and still doesn't.
                db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            else
            {
                // New value exists that didn't before.
                db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }

        // Review each attribute that DID previously exist.
        foreach (ProductAttribute pa in product.ProductAttributes
            .Intersect(existingAttributes, new ProductAttributeComparer()))
        {
            if (pa.Value is null)
            {
                // Value existed and has been cleared.
                db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            else
            {
                if (pa.Value != existingAttributes
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute == pa.Attribute).Value)
                {
                    // Value has been altered.
                    db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Value has not been altered.
                    db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = product.ProductId });
    }
    return View(product);
}

internal class ProductAttributeComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductAttribute>
{
    public bool Equals(ProductAttribute x, ProductAttribute y)
    {
        if (string.Equals(x.Attribute, y.Attribute, 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductAttribute obj)
    {
        return obj.Attribute.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: anything with linq has a performance hit.

Comment: The performance hit was more than expected and seemed to add a second or two specifically to SaveChanges. I think I was triggering record locks or tracking by comparing two ienumerables from the same model.

Comment: yeah and it may have been retrieving the record multiple times. I avoid Linq specific queries whenever possible. Surely the update command in sql now only updates the different field rather than a whole record?

Please include your code to see if there is any way of optimising it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example.

Comment: if the default state for each item is unchanged you can get rid of that else
else
                {
                    // Value has not been altered.
                    db.Entry(pa).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }

Comment: Thank you, Slipoch.